# laravel 5 custom method in model with query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my Room object I want to get an Picture with the lowest priority. So to my Room model i've  added:

```
public function picture(){
    Return Picture::where('room_id', $this->id)->orderBy('priority', 'asc')->first();
}
```

In my controller I call this method like:

```
public function($id){
  $room = Room::findOrFail($id); 
  $room->picture();
}
```

But when i try to get it in my view like:

```
 {{$room->picture}}
```

I get the following error:

**Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation**

When using {{$room}} I dont see any picture object in the room object but the app doesnt crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to fetch the latest picture like that, you'll need to put relation definition in your **pictures()** method instead of fetching the object. This way you'll be able to make use of Eloquent's eager loading; fetching the picture with the lowest (in terms of value) priority will also be very easy.

Add the following to your **Room** class:

```
//relation definition - one to many
public function pictures() {
  return $this->hasMany(Picture::class);
}

//Eloquent getter
public function getPictureAttribute() {
  return $this->pictures()->orderBy('priority', 'asc')->first();
}
```

Now, you can easily access the most important picture on a **$room** object by doing:

```
$picture = $room->picture;
```

You can read more about how to set up different types of relations in your models here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I thought it would be bad practise to do it like that, because now you select all and than filter instead of select one or am i wrong ?

Comment: No. first() is called on the query builder and it adds "limit 1" to the query, so only one object is fetched from the database

Comment: @jedrzej.kuylo i get the following erro: Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

Comment: Where? pictures() is returning Relation object, maybe you have some other relations defined incorrectly? Could you paste your model code?

Comment: Did you remove the original "picture()" method? It was causing such error, if it's still there that's the reason. Remove it

Comment: I used it exactly like your example also tried $room->picture() note the "()". i removed all my original methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84738/discussion-between-jedrzej-kurylo-and-sven-b).